# How to change button color when radio input is selected, but input is wrapped in div before label?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I am trying to make our dinky radio buttons into lovely toggle buttons on our donation page. The HTML cannot be modified, and as it stands the inputs are wrapped in divs, then followed by the labels. I have zero knowledge of JS/jQuery and I imagine this task requires some.

Here is my fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/cgz63qhd/

```css
body {
  padding: 10px;
  font-family: sans-serif;
}

div.donation-levels {
  margin: 3px 0;
}

.donation-level-container {
  display: inline-block;
}

.donation-level-container input {
  visibility: hidden;
}

.donation-level-amount-container {
  text-align: center;
  margin: 5px 2px;
  padding: 0.7em 2em;
  color: #ffffff;
  background-color: #1a92b4;
  border-radius: 5px;
  display: inline-block;
  cursor: pointer;
  font-size: 22px;
}

.donation-level-amount-container:hover {
  background: #e8525f;
  color: #ffffff;
}

.donation-level-label-input-container input:checked~label {
  background: #e8525f;
}
```

```html
<div class="donation-level-container">
  <div class="form-content">

    <div class="donation-level-input-container form-input">

      <div class="donation-level-label-input-container">
        <input name="level_flexibleexpanded" id="level_flexibleexpanded5942" value="5942" onclick="evalMatchingGift('$35.00');" type="radio">
      </div>

      <label for="level_flexibleexpanded5942" onclick="">


    <div class="donation-level-amount-container">
    $35.00
    </div>

    </label>

    </div>

    <input name="level_flexibleexpandedsubmit" id="level_flexible_5942expandedsubmit" value="true" type="hidden">
  </div>
</div>
<div class="donation-level-container">
  <div class="form-content">

    <div class="donation-level-input-container form-input">

      <div class="donation-level-label-input-container">
        <input name="level_flexibleexpanded" id="level_flexibleexpanded5943" value="5943" onclick="evalMatchingGift('$60.00');" type="radio">
      </div>

      <label for="level_flexibleexpanded5943" onclick="">

    <div class="donation-level-amount-container">
    $60.00
    </div>

    </label>

    </div>

    <input name="level_flexibleexpandedsubmit" id="level_flexible_5943expandedsubmit" value="true" type="hidden">
  </div>
</div>
<div class="donation-level-container">
  <div class="form-content">

    <div class="donation-level-input-container form-input">

      <div class="donation-level-label-input-container">
        <input name="level_flexibleexpanded" id="level_flexibleexpanded5944" value="5944" onclick="evalMatchingGift('$120.00');" type="radio">
      </div>

      <label for="level_flexibleexpanded5944" onclick="">

    <div class="donation-level-amount-container">
    $120.00
    </div>

    </label>


    </div>

    <input name="level_flexibleexpandedsubmit" id="level_flexible_5944expandedsubmit" value="true" type="hidden">
  </div>
</div>
```

Here is my inspiration donate page: https://action.audubon.org/donate/now

Alas, their labels are set up better so I think they were able to make the buttons with pure CSS (?).

My buttons currently are looking decent, are sized fine and colored nicely, but they just won't stay that coral color when clicked! Can someone help me out?

I've seen a lot of questions here on this topic but I can't seem to get anything to work.

I'm sure there are other issues in the code, please point them out if you see them!

Comment: for each button just have a label and an input to hold the donation amount. You have too many div containers for each of them.

Comment: @athar13 As I mentioned above, the HTML cannot be modified. Believe me, this would be much easier if I could change it!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need this piece of jQuery:

```
$(function() {
  $(document).on('click','.donation-level-amount-container',function(){
    $('.donation-level-amount-container').removeClass('active');
    $(this).addClass('active');
  });
});
```

Update also to this CSS:

```
.donation-level-amount-container:hover, .donation-level-amount-container.active { 
    background:#e8525f;
    color:#ffffff; 
}
```

Here is the updated [jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/cgz63qhd/1/).

Comment: This is beautiful! It works perfectly on the fiddle. I'm so sorry for my lack of knowledge, but how do I put the jQuery (?) in? Like does it just get wrapped in <script> at the bottom of my page? Edit: because when I add the script to my page, it doesn't work. :(

Comment: Have you embedded the jquery library somewhere? This have to be embedded first and after that this piece of code.

Answer (score 2):

```
$(".donation-level-amount-container").on("click", function() {
  $('.donation-level-amount-container').each(function() {
      $(this).removeClass('active');
    });    
  $(this).toggleClass('active');
})
```

And css

```
.active {
  background:#e8525f;
  color:#ffffff; 
}
```

Working fiddle:
https://jsfiddle.net/29exoa4k/2/

Comment: Yeah this answer is right, but why this gets upvotes and my answer not? My answer was even earlier. :D

Answer (score 0):

You want something like this

```
$(".donation-level-amount-container").on("click", function() {
    $(this).css("background", "red");
})
```

or to toggle an active class

```
$(".donation-level-amount-container").on("click", function() {
    $(this).toggleClass("active");
})
```

Comment: Then the background will always be red.

Comment: In that case they can just use .toggleClass('active') :)

Comment: When you just use `toggleClass` you can `select` multiple options at the same time.

Answer (score 0):

You need this

```
$(".donation-level-amount-container").on("click", function() {
    $(".donation-level-amount-container").css("background", "#1a92b4");
    $(this).css("background", "#e8525f");
})
```

and css !important for background property

```
.donation-level-amount-container:hover { 
    background:#e8525f!important;
    color:#ffffff; 
}
```

here's your updated fiddle https://jsfiddle.net/cgz63qhd/3/

Answer (score 0):

Indeed, this can not be done with pure CSS, since you can't traverse upward in the DOM using CSS selectors. As previous answers mentioned, it can easily be done with jQuery, but it can also be done in vanilla javascript.

```
var donationButtons = document.querySelectorAll('.donation-level-amount-container');
var defaultBg = '#1a92b4';
var activeBg = '#f00';

donationButtons.forEach(function(btn){
    btn.onclick = function(){
        donationButtons.forEach(function(btn){
            // deselect previously selected buttons
            btn.style.background = defaultBg;
        });
        this.style.background = activeBg;
    }
});
```

I'm certain this can be done smoother, but this is the first solution that popped up in my head.